# Breaking out of function in c++

Tags: c++, function

how do you leave a function in the middle? i have a condition for leaving the function, but i dont know how to actually leave.

ex:

```
void a(int &num){
    if (num > 100){
        // leave function
    }
    num += a(num + 1);
}
```

i want to end the recursion, and i have to keep the function a `void`

Comment: What? `a` returns `void`, how can you do `num += a(anything);`? And how does `num+1` bind to a non-const reference? Is there an `int a(int num);` somewhere, so that last call isn't directly recursive? Not that it matters in this case because I don't think it affects the answer, but in general you get better answers asking about real code.

Answer (score 11):

```
void a(int &num){
    if (num > 100){
        return;
    }
    num += a(num + 1);
}
```

As pointed in the comments by Martin York, I jumped on the answer without considering every aspect of the question, and for that I apologize. What you want is probably :

```
int a(int num)
{
    if (num > 100)
         return num;
    return num + a(num + 1);
}
```

Comment: You can write `num += a(num + 1);` The function a() does not return a value. Please make sure it compiles before you post.

Comment: Martin York: Don't you mean "you _can't_ write `num += a(num + 1);`"? As you said, `a()` doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing stops you from putting a `return` in the middle of the function, although some people may argue that it's bad style.

The main motivation for that idea is that if you have multiple return points in your function it's more difficult to maintain the cleanup code, that will have to be spread at each return; however, using the modern [RAII pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (that is required if you want your code to be exception-safe) you should have no problems in having multiple exit points: the cleanup code (that is contained in the destructors of the resource-holding objects) will be called anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use return.

But you need a value:

```
int a(int num)
{
    if (num > 100)
    {
        return num;
    }
    num += a(num + 1);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: @DeadMG: Not when I copied it. The OP has chaged the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
void a(int num)
{
    if (num > 100)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        num += a(num + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function returns a value, a `return` statement with a value needs to be given:

```
int a(int num){
    if (num > 100){
        return 100;// leave function
    }
    num += a(num + 1);
    return num;
}
```

For functions not returning a value, use `return;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a(int num){
    if (num > 100){
        return num;  // or return 100;
    }
    num += a(num + 1);
    return num;
}
```

By the way if your are using references (int &num) you can not pass num + 1 as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. Notice that no return value is needed since it is a void function. and the void is very empty.

```
void a(int &num){
    if (num > 100){
        return;
    }
    num += a(num + 1);
 }
```

But I rather see the code sample above like this.

```
void a(int &num){
    if(!(num >100)){
        num += a(num + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Some people don't like to have more than one return statement in a function:

```
void a(..)
{
  if (...)
    goto end;
  ....
end:
  return;
}
```

I, on the other hand, think they're stupid.

Yes, I've seen it.

Comment: They're certainly not looking too clever if that's their way of writing `if (!(...)) { ... } return;`

Comment: Replacing a `return` with a `goto` is just... _euch!_

Comment: Guess someone thinks this is the right way to do it.  Sorry I bad mouthed your coding standard :p

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with coding guidelines that say exactly this (and it drives me up the wall as it makes writing the code a lot harder to get correct (as you release resources after `end:` and thus you must have everything initialized before the first `goto` (and it just makes things hard))).

Comment: Some coding guidelines make you wonder.  Was it come up with before anyone thought of scope guarding?  Bet you're not allowed to use exceptions too :p

Comment: 1) SESE is so 1980. 2) goto isn't less spaghetti than multiple returns can be (if done wrong) 3) possible cleanup code isn't executed if exceptions are thrown, so better use RAII

Comment: @Martin: I'm interesting those coding guidelines (well, maybe "morbidly fascinated" would be more accurate). Are they public? Do they mandate the use of `goto`, or merely forbid multiple returns? Could you follow the letter of the guidelines by writing: `if (!(...)) { ... } goto end; end: return;`, so that the function contains a `goto` as required? ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Currently fighting to get this removed. If you have any documents that would help I would love the references. Rules are: 1) Initialize all variables at top 2) Don't put good code in 'ifStatement' use this for 'goto exit'. 3) Do resource cleanup after exit label. 4) Single return.

Comment: @Martin: Hmm, so "don't put good code in if statement" is the serious problem here, I think. Sounds like they're just opposed in principle to structured programming, putting them about 40 years behind the cutting edge. I don't have any specific references to counter their brand of crazy, but maybe try to attack on the basis of what they do in cases of "if" statements where both cases are "good", but different. Presumably they have "good" code in "if" statements then. So why do differently just because one branch does nothing?

Comment: I actually don't hate the use of goto to jump to the correct point in a cleanup sequence, it avoids deeply nested arrow code and (very) occasionally allows a control flow that's intuitive and clear, but not well-expressed by if statements. But I wouldn't mandate it, and *especially* not in functions that only nest one or two conditions deep anyway. Mandating that all return paths go through the (single) cleanup sequence ending in return should be adequate, I don't see why it should be better to reach the sequence via goto rather than any other control structure.

Comment: ... all this assuming no RAII, presumably for some unholy reason such as "not invented here", or "we want to use the same style for C and C++".

Comment: What is "good code"?  Does the rule mean that you only put "bad code" in if statements?  As to initialize all variables at the top, there's actually decent articles to the contrary on the intertubes.